# Spring Jpa Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am new to Spring Jpa Queries, basically I have 2 fields in my query that I am looking for a result.

```
String projectName
Integer sequenceId;
```

So far I have:

```
    returnedObject findLastByProjectNameAndSequenceId(String projectName);
```

What I am trying to do is find the last ID associated with a specific project name, I am wondering is this doable with spring query like this or will I have to use @Query?

Comment: does `Integer findLastSequenceIdByProjectName(String projectName)` work?

Comment: No errors on compile, testing now  -- it may work.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort by id desc and get the first item

```
returnedObject findFirstByProjectNameOrderBySequenceIdDesc(String projectName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`findFirstByProjectNameAndSequenceIdOrderByProjectNameDesc(String projectName, String sequenceId)`